# Delete timer jobs

Tags: timer-jobs, powershell

I have a couple of timer jobs that I cant get rid of.  I think they got created as a consequnce of creating a custom job.

Also, if I use powershell Get-SPTimerJob then I get an exception.

```
Get-SPTimerJob : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
At line:1 char:15
+ Get-SPTimerJob <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletGetTimerJob:SPCmdletGetTimerJob) [Get-SPTimerJob], T
   argetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetTimerJob
```

Anyone got any idea how I can remove the jobs in 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these timer jobs refer to your own GAC based DLLs then try removing them from the GAC and restarting the timer service. There may be problems with deserialisation of custom job data.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it.

As for  Get-SPTimerJobs, it works if I specify -WebApplication but fails for everything else.

Cheers

Comment: Blogged about it here: http://jonesie.net.nz/2010/05/05/SharePoint2010CustomTimerJobs.aspx