# Is there a PowerShell cmdlet to delete a Timer Job?

Tags: powershell

Is there a PowerShell cmdlet to delete a Timer Job in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't have a spare timer job to test this with currently, but this should work, replacing **mysitecleanup** with the name of your timer job.

```
$jobToDelete = Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.name -eq "mysitecleanup" }
$jobToDelete.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get-SPTimerJob cmdlet, and possibly delete from there. Check out [Delete timer jobs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/delete-timer-jobs) for a trick on removing a job...