# Delete multiple Timer Jobs with Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs

It is possible to delete a time job using Powershell and the following command:

```
Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like "*JobName*" } |ft id,name
$job = Get-SPTimerJob -id {JobID}
$job.Delete()
```

Is it also possible to do this for all TimerJob which are returned by `Get-SPTimerJob`?

EDIT: I am looking for an answer and a working code snippet which will do as I described above.

Comment: I would assume that is very easy to test.

Comment: okay and on which basis are you assuming? references?

Comment: I am assuming based on experience. You probably tested your original query? If you did, test the one where you remove multiple timer jobs.

Comment: ehm, I am looking for an answer for my question and optionally for a correct command (have updated the question)...

Comment: Kindly check here...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22368/is-there-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-delete-a-timer-job

Answer (score 1):

> here is the PowerShell script that takes only one input as the guid of
>   the timer job and deletes it.
>
> Here is the script :
>
> ```
> param([string]$jobid)
>
> [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
>
>
> function oDeleteTimerJob($jobid) {
>
>     write-host "This script will delete a timer job"
>         $farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
>         $services = $farm.Services
>         foreach($service in $services)
> {
>
> $jobdefs = $service.JobDefinitions
> foreach($job in $jobdefs)
> {
>        if($job.Id.ToString() -eq $jobid)
> {
>
>           $job.Delete()
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }
>
> write-host "The job is deleted"
>
> }
>
> oDeleteTimerJob $jobid
> ```

I got reference from below MSDN link

[How to delete a timer job using powershell in sharepoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11790.how-to-delete-a-timer-job-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.aspx)

Comment: pfuu, thanks dude but I think I will use my option due to less code and more redability.

Answer (score 0):

okay, thanks to @Hardik's comment I ended up with the following:

```
$jobToDelete = Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like "*jobName*" }
$jobToDelete.Delete()
```

That was easy :D

Comment: Nice to see working code for you in answer. My Pleasure. :)

Comment: @Hardik I would have also gave you the answer points ;)

Comment: Thanks dude, You can choose any of the method as my given answer contains the precise code to do so. Anyway you are your own BOSS..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-SPTimerJob -WebApplication "http://devsite" | ForEach-Object{ 
   Write-Host $_.id "|" $_.name
   $_.Delete()
}
```

This is another way to do it.

Note: This gives all timer jobs associated with your webapplication specified

Edit:

```
Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like "*jobName*" }| ForEach-Object{ 
    Write-Host $_.id "|" $_.name
    $_.Delete()
}
```

This will delete jobs having the name mentioned in 1st statement that is `jobName`

Comment: but one has to know what he is doing to run this code! otherwise...

Comment: Both options iterates through each timer job returned by `Get-SPTimerJob` as you were requesting. Which finally I am deleting

Comment: I have added a line before deleting, which shows Id and name of timer job